# sequelize with typescript can not use .create with type attributes

Tags: mysql, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

The `IDBAttribute` -

```
interface IDBAtribute {
    readonly id: number;
    readonly createdAt: Date;
    readonly updatedAt: Date;
}
```

The User attributes -

```
interface IDBMoviesAttributes extends IDBAttribute {
    readonly title: string;
    readonly description: string;
    readonly category: string;
    readonly release_date: number;
    readonly movie_hour_length: number;
    readonly movie_minute_length: number;
    readonly image_path: string;
    readonly video_path: string;
}
```

The User model -

```
import { BuildOptions, DataTypes, Model, Sequelize } from "sequelize";

import { IDBUserAttributes } from "./shared/db-table";

interface UserModel extends Model<IDBUserAttributes>, IDBUserAttributes {}

class User extends Model<UserModel, IDBUserAttributes> {}

type UserStatic = typeof Model & {
  new (values?: object, options?: BuildOptions): UserModel;
};

const UserFactory = (sequelize: Sequelize): UserStatic => {
  return <UserStatic>sequelize.define("users", {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(320),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(26),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
    },
  });
}

export {
  UserModel,
  User,
  UserFactory,
  UserStatic,
}
```

I'm Using the `User` for `.create` method in sequelize like this -

```
User.create({
      email: req.body.email,
      username: req.body.username,
      password: hashedPassword,
    })
```

The error -

```
Argument of type '{ email: string; username: string; password: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IDBUserAttributes'.
  Type '{ email: string; username: string; password: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'IDBUserAttributes': id, createdAt, updatedAtts(2345)
```

I know to error is type error but i don't know any other why to the `User` model, is there any other way I can achive that? I don't need to create the id,createdAt, updatedAt.

How can I get the model in the correct way?

Comment: What it the definition of `IDBUserAttributes`?

Comment: @EmmanuelPonnudurai the interface of the user in DB

Answer (score 1):

Try making id ,createdAt ,updatedAt as Optional(?) in IDBUserAttributes.
It might work

Example:

```js
interface IDBUserAttributes {
    id?: number;
    createdAt?: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const newObjectData: Request['body'] = {
  user_id: 1
};
```

and now, you can use "create" method like this;

```
await Model.create(newObjectData);
```